# How to keep a counter for removed duplicates inside a hash value?

Tags: perl, hash, duplicates

```
chdir("c:/perl/normalized");
$docid=0;
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );
my %hash = ();
@files = <*>;
foreach $file (@files) 
  {
    $docid++;
    open (input, $file);    
    while (<input>) 
      {
    open (output,'>>c:/perl/postinglist/total');
    chomp;
    (@words) = split(" ");  
    foreach $word (@words)
    {
    push @{ $hash{$word} }, $docid;

    }
      }
   }
foreach $key (sort keys %hash) 
{
    $size = scalar (@{$hash{$key}});    
    print output "Term: $key,   Frequency:$size,    Document(s):", join(" ", uniq @{ $hash{$key} }), "\n";
}


close (input);
close (output);
```

before the `join(" ", uniq @{ $hash{$key} })` the output was as follows:

```
Term:of Frequency:35  Document(s): 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

Documents shows where was the the frequency distributed

```
Term:of Frequency:35  Document(s):1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

which is fine until here... how ever I want to keep a counter for the remove duplicates and such my new output would be

```
Term:of Frequency:35  Document(s) of: 1(10) 2(7) 3(2) 4(4) 5(1) 6(2) 7(9)
```

that is value(counter)

I was able to fix my own problem by making some changes to my source code

```
chdir("c:/perl/normalized");
$docid=0;
my %hash = ();
@files = <*>;
foreach $file (@files) 
  {$counter=0;
    $docid++;
    open (input, $file);    
    while (<input>) 
      {
    open (output,'>>c:/perl/tokens/total');
    chomp;
    (@words) = split(" ");  
    foreach $word (@words)
    { 

     push @{ $hash{$word}{$docid}},$counter;
    @{$hash{$word}{$docid}}[$counter]++;


    }
      }
   }

foreach my $line (sort keys %hash) {
        print output "Term:$line \n";
        foreach my $elem (sort keys %{$hash{$line}}) {
            print output"  Doc:$elem " . "freq:".@{$hash{$line}->{$elem}} . "\n";
        }
    }


close (input);
close (output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Best bet might be to use a hash instead of an array, and maintain a count as the value of the hash. Change

```
push @{ $hash{$word} }, $docid;
```

to

```
++$hash{$word}{$docid};
```

Use `keys` to get the doc ids. You'll lose the order, but it can easily be restored using a numerical sort.

Comment: 1. You seem to have forgotten to show your code and tell us your problem, then. 2. Actually, arrays can't hold more than one value for each of its keys. Arrays themselves can hold more than one value, but so can hashes. Whichever way you look at it, this statement of yours makes no sense.

Comment: I never said sequential. Not sure what you mean by "another term" since you only gave one. You also didn't explain anything about how term relates to your question.

Comment: Anyway, you seem to think your question is deficient. So go fix it up instead of writing all these comments.

Comment: It worked :)!!! what you said was wrong ++$hash{$word}{$docid};it gives an error
the correct answer  @{$hash{$word}{$docid}}[$counter]++; Thank you for the tip and thank you for your time and effort

Comment: wtf is $counter?!?! There's no such variable in your program. (PS -- Your code is a wrong way to write `++$hash{$word}{$docid}[$counter];`)